# Laravel's Model::create() function isn't setting a custom field value

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

Laravel newbie here, sorry if this is painfully obvious but I've been stuck on it for ages!

**Objective**: To mass-assign a `Quote::create()` database insertion with the full values from the form, *plus* set the User ID to the currently logged in user.

**Problem**: The `user_id` column is never written to the database. Every other column is, but `user_id` remains as 0.

I have of course tried adding `user_id` to the `$fillable` array, but I don't want it to be user-fillable - I want it to be set by Laravel's `Auth::id()` function.

Any ideas why this won't get stored? Is it because the `$quote->create()` function doesn't factor in previously set data and just takes its parameter as everything to be saved? If so how do I do this?

Here's my controller's `store()` function:

```
/**
     * Stores a created quote in the database
     *
     * @param QuoteRequest $request
     *
     */
    public function store(QuoteRequest $request)
    {
        // This method will only get fired if QuoteRequest passes
        $quote = new Quote;
        $quote->user_id = Auth::id();
        $quote->create($request->all());

        echo 'Job done';
    }
```

Here's my `Quote` model:

```
<?php namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Auth;

class Quote extends Model {

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'quotes';

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'quote_person',
        'quote_value',
        'quote_date'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [ ];

    /*
     * Request/User many-to-one relationship
     */
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }

    /*
     * Belongs to current User scope
     */
    public function scopeMine($query)
    {
        return $query->where('user_id', Auth::id());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this and see if it works.

```
public function store(QuoteRequest $request)
{
    // This method will only get fired if QuoteRequest passes
    $quote = new Quote;
    $quote->fill($request->all());
    $quote->user_id = Auth::id();
    $quote->save();

    echo 'Job done';
}
```

Comment: Or just `$quote = new Quote($request->all()); $quote->user_id = ...`

Comment: This certainly does work, thank you. So what advantages/disadvantages does `save()` offer over `create()` then? Am I still protected from mass assignments when using `save()`?

Comment: @Jack Yes, you're safe. `$quote->fill` respects your mass assignment settings. `save()` just saves the resulting data from your mass and manual assignment calls.

Comment: the fill method respects the fillable property of the model as well. We first fill the new model with whatever input was passed then assign other properties (user_id here) explicitly

Comment: And if just called `new Quote($request->all())` directly, does passing a request in also respect the mass assignment settings in the same was a `fill()` does? Thank you so much for the clear explanations everyone!

Comment: Looking at the [source](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L259) the `fill()` method is called in the constructor as well :)

Comment: If you have the relationship set up on the user model, you can do this all in one line: `Auth::user()->quotes()->create($request->all());` Better yet, you can get rid of the `Auth` facade and get the user from the request: `$request->user()->quotes()->create($request->all());`.

Answer (score 3):

The `create` function is considered mass assignment and is thusly affected by `$fillable` / `$guarded`. It's also a static function, so `$quote->create()` is making an entirely new Eloquent instance - that's why your manually assigned `user_id` is lost.

You can use `Model::unguard()` to temporarily turn off the protection.

Comment: An entirely new Eloquent instance - that makes sense, thanks. I guess in practice I wouldn't want to unguard the model for security reasons - so what's the way around this? Is it as Pawel's answer suggests?

Comment: @Jack Yes, Pawel's answer is ideal in that situation.